# R.string.XXX returns an int from strings.xml when I need a String

Tags: java, android, undefined

This is sort of a continuation of this thread:

[Localizing strings in strings.xml gives NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16362524/localizing-strings-in-strings-xml-gives-nullpointerexception)

This issue arose after going through and implementing the solution provided in that thread.  The solution provided worked for instances like this:

```
loading = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.loading);
loading.setText(R.string.loading);
```

This does not work for situations like below:

```
exodus.add(new Question(R.string.a, R.string.b, R.string.c, R.string.d, 0, R.string.e, -1, R.string.f));
```

The error is `The constructor Question(int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int) is undefined`.  The contructor for Question is supposed to be `Question(String, String, String, String, int, String, int, String)` but these:

```
R.string.X
```

are returning as ints instead of Strings.

What can I do to fix this problem?  And also, if you know, why is this method working for setting text of `TextView`s but not parameters in objects?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`R.string.*` is a reference to an int in R.java that points to your actual String.

Use `context.getResources().getString(R.string.*);` to get the actual String value.

Comment: Please refer to the link in my opening post.  That is what I was doing initially but that was not working.  It was giving me a NPE.

Comment: @Matt That's probably because your Context is null at that point.

Comment: Try adding `c = this;` inside your onCreate() method

Comment: @Matt or you could use just `getResources().getString(R.id.*);`

Comment: That too. But the `this` thing will fix your NPE.

Comment: @RaghavSood - The `c = this;` seems to be what I was looking for.  One more question: for the classes that don't extend Activity, where do I initialize the `Context c`?  It seems whereever I put it I get a `type mismatch` error.  For example, the `exodus.add(new Question(c.getResources().getString(R.id.*, ....);` is in a class that does not extend an activity.

Comment: Matt,

Since it's not an activity, you can use the application's context by calling getApplicationContext().getResources()....

Or, create a class that extends Application (if you already don't have it), say that class is called MainApp (extend Application), create a private static variable private static MainApp appContext;, and simply create a public static getAppContext(){return appContext;}

Now you can just call MainApp.getAppContext() if you need context outside of an activity or service

Comment: Thank you @vkinra!  All working!

Comment: @RaghavSood - Feel free to post the correct answer on that other thread and I will mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 7):

Please refer to this 
[StackOverFlow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493287/android-how-do-i-get-string-from-resources-using-its-name)

```
String mystring = getResources().getString(R.string.mystring);
```

Answer (score 4):

For your last question:

You are using the [setText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28int%29) method prototype which takes a resid argument, not a `String`, that's why it's working. `R.string.loading` returns an `int` representing that resid. Had you been calling the `setText` method with the `getString(R.string.loading)` argument, then it would have used the [setText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) prototype.

Comment: If you read further down on your link, it clearly has `setText(CharSequence text)`. A `CharSequence` is a `String`. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049228/charsequence-vs-string-in-java).

Comment: `R.string.loading` represents an `int` (check R class to see its value), hence the method I mentioned. If you do `getString(R.string.loading)`, then you have a string to use in the method you mentioned.

Comment: `R.string.loading` is an `int`, I'm not disputing that and I know that already. But what you are stating in the answer is that you cannot use a `String` in `setText`, a `String` is different from `R.string`, and you can in fact use `String` with `setText`. So what you are saying in your answer is still wrong.

Comment: I'm not saying that he cannot use a `String`, but that the method prototype he's using takes an `int`, not a `String`, hence the reason why it's working for him.

Comment: You mean it takes a `String` not an `int`...? And what method prototype?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29389/discussion-between-voicu-and-troniczomb)